# How to create SSL certificate for different domain and user?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, ssl-certificate

I created a certificate request using IIS on my development PC. Everything went fine and I successfully established SSL connection with the server when using Visual Studio 2015 with my main AD domain account.

However, the development of the new system is done using another AD domain (and account), and the newly created certificate doesn't work with this account. I have assumed that the certificate is generated per machine, and not per user.

There's no option to select for which account the certificate is created, so how can I create a certificate request for different account/domain? Or is there something else I'm missing?

The exception I'm getting (from a .NET application, using a client generated from a WSDL definition): "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority xxxxx.com". The application works when it's ran on my default AD credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes to the to which certificates your client trusts. To gain this trust you can:

1. (not recommended) Disable server certificate validation (setting ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback or something similar)
2. For server side, use certificate that is issued by known certificate authority(CA) like Verisign, Go Daddy, etc. On client computers - you get those CA certificates already installed with Windows.
3. If you issue certificates yourself, on the client computer/server you must add public part of the certificate to the Trusted People certificate store. Or if you issue certificates on the AD, add domain CA certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on you client computer/server.